# Error invoking a powershell/powercli script via ssh in Windows 2022

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have a weird issue in the execution of a powershell script with powercli components in Windows Server 2022 invoked via ssh from a linux system.

It only works when the invoking user is logged into the Windows Server via VMWare Remote Console (I assume the same would happen if logged in via RDP, cannot try it due to firewall restrictions), otherwise it cannot stablish the connection with the VMWare ViCenter.

We have a web dashboard hosted in a Linux, where operators can launch actions on different servers through a menu.
One of those actions calls an `sh` in the same server, which establishes a connections via ssh with a Windows Server 2022. The authentication is done via key exchange, not interactive password. The whole idea is that the operator launches the command and then just monitors how it finishes.

*From now on I'll refer to the components of the architecture as LINUX, WINDOWS, VICENTER, USER, etc... all in caps for security concerns.*

The architecture is LINUX(sh) → WINDOWS(ps1) → VICENTER, all connections and executions with USER.

The first script, the sh, is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# variables
var1=$1
var2=$2

# command
ssh -i /home/apps_consola/.ssh/USER_id_dsa USER@WINDOWS powershell.exe C:\\scripts\\Mover_VM_entre_sitios.ps1 $var1 $var2
```

*Where `$1` is the DESTINATION SITE and `$2` is the VM to move. Received from the dashboard, and pass from the sh to the ps1.*

The ps1 launches and it's supposed to connect with our VMWare VICENTER, and move a VM from the production site to the contingency one. And here is where the problem manifests:

- If USER is logged into WINDOWS, the script works like a charm. Also works ok if launched by hand.
- If USER is not logged into WINDOWS, the script launches but can never establish the connection with the VICENTER.

The connection between WINDOWS and VICENTER is established inside the ps1 as follows:

```
$Credentials = Get-VICredentialStoreItem -Host VICENTER -File C:\Scripts\Cred.xml 
Connect-VIServer VICENTER -User $Credentials.User -Password $Credentials.Password
```

The Cred.xml file was created with `New-VICredentialStoreItem -User DOMAIN\USER -Password PASSWORD -Host VICENTER -File Cred.xml` locally on WINDOWS with the USER, which is in the local Administrators Group.

The ps1 never even cancels, I have to manually kill the process for it to end and the error I get is:

```
Get-VICredentialStoreItem : The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation
and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.
At C:\SCRIPTS\Mover_VM_entre_sitios.ps1:15 char:16
+ ... edentials = Get-VICredentialStoreItem -Host VICENTER -File C:\Scripts ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-VICredentialStoreItem], CryptographicException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_GetVICredentialStoreItem_ProcessRecordget,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetVICredentialStoreItem
```

For what I read online, it might be an issue with the double hop of credentials, but I tried everything I found and still cannot make it work.

I've already run this commands in an elevated Powershell console logged in as USER:

```
enable-wsmancredssp -Role client -DelegateComputer * -Verbose
enable-wsmancredssp -Role server
enable-psremoting
```

Checking with `get-wsmancredssp` I get:

```
The machine is configured to allow delegating fresh credentials to the following target(s): wsman/*;wsman/*.DOMAIN
This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote client computer.
```

I also modified the following Local Policies (through gpedit.msc):

```
Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Right Assignments\Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation: I added the USER

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credentials Delegation\Allow delegating fresh credentials: I enabled it and added LINUX, WINDOWS, VICENTER, wsman/*.DOMAIN and wsman/*

Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credentials Delegation\Allow delegating fresh credentials with NTLM-only server authentication:  I enabled it and added LINUX, WINDOWS, VICENTER, wsman/*.DOMAIN and wsman/*
```

I also read that adding the REG_DWORD ProtectionPolicy set to 1 in the branch of the registry: \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb, but the issue persists.

I have to mention that we had this same setup working just fine, but due to a unrecoverable error we lost the WINDOWS component (the old VM was a win 2012r2). The situation described is happening in the broken VM replacement (WINDOWS). And I don't remember getting any of this errors in the previous one, as I recall there was no configuration needed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Most Systems have moved from Windows Credentials to AUTH2.  OAUTH2 works on Windows, Linux, and Mac.  You are using SSH and following may help : https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/ssh-windows

Comment: Thanks @jdweng, but the error happens when the Windows server tries to connect to the vmware vicenter when the user isn´t logged into the system. It´s not an ssh issue, it's some kind of problem with the authentication in that escenario it seeams

Comment: SSH is the authentication.  It is part of the protocol.

Comment: @jdweng ssh is part of the connect-viserver command?? Are you positive about that? We have the port 22 closed on the ViSerever. I've now identified that the issue is with the viCredentialStoreItem method of authentication. If instead I use domain\user and password it works fine (but I cant leave the password in plain text in the script)

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell   Most windows systems require you get a credential instead of using username/password (not encrypted).  The credential will use the user login to get an encrypted credential.  But you are going between windows and linux.  See : https://containerssh.io/v0.4/blog/2021/04/13/devlog-oauth2/

Comment: It’s failing to read the creds, maybe hanging because user/pw are null. As a test, does it work with psremoting instead of ssh? A VMware forums post mentioned the VICredentialstore cmdlets do not work with ps v7. You’re not calling pwsh.exe, but it makes me wonder if they also don’t work from ssh. Maybe an issue with HKCU being loaded vs not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed strategy and went with a secureString encryption. It isolates the encrypted pwd in a file from the user/machine that generated it.
Thanks anyway for those who answered :)

Answer (score 0):

If the VICredentialStore (which apparently relies on the Windows DPAPI) does not play nice under SSH, maybe this VMware.VISecret  module is a workaround

https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2023/02/managing-vicredentials-on-powershell-7-using-vmware-visecret-module.html

[This post](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/452#issuecomment-268627151) seems relevant to the failure: "SSH remote sessions are run under the context of the client user. They are however network logon sessions and do not have user's credentials attached. DPAPI encryption and decryption only work with interactive logon sessions in general (or other specific logon sessions that have user's credentials attached), since these APIs actually use user's password to do the encryption and decryption."

Edit: a later comment in the same thread states "with password auth, remote session has user creds. So DPAPI works". The VICredentialStore seems worth another try with password (instead of key) authentication, at least as a test. If that fails, another test with psremoting instead of ssh might reveal more about what's going on.